# Get keys of Record<string, {}> (or define object with inferred keys and typed values) in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I have an interface `MyInterface` and a const/readonly dictionary of string keys to that interface.

```ts
interface MyInterface {
  someProp: number;
}

const MyObj: Record<string, MyInterface> = {
  myKey1: { someProp: 1 },
  myKey2: { someProp: 2 },
} as const;
```

Now I want to create a `type` which is the keys of `MyObj`.

```ts
type MyKeys = keyof typeof MyObj; // MyKeys = string
```

Alternatively, I can do

```ts
const MyObj = {
  myKey1: { someProp: 1 },
  myKey2: { someProp: 2 },
} as const;

type MyKeys = keyof typeof MyObj; // MyKeys = 'myKey1' | 'myKey2'
```

This gets us the desired type, but doesn't give us type safety within `MyObj`.

Unsurprisingly, this does not work.

```ts
const MyObj: Record<keyof typeof MyObj, MyInterface> = {
  // ...
}
```

Is there a way to get both type safety and the keys without knowing the keys in advance?  Preferably, I'd like to do this without a wrapper function, but if there's no other way, I might be able to convince my team it's worth it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have iterated a bit the accepted solution by @dx_over_dt with the advantage of `satisfies` operator introduced in typescript 4.9. It goes as follows (using the same example as the accepted solution)

```
interface MyInterface {
  someProp: number;
}

function makeMyObj<T extends Record<string, MyInterface>>(
  obj: T,
): { [key in keyof T]: MyInterface } {
  return obj
}

const MyObj = makeMyObj({
  myKey1: { someProp: 1 },
  myKey2: { someProp: 2 },
} satisfies Record<string, MyInterface>);

type MyKeys = keyof typeof MyObj;
```

This way, you can have the best of both worlds, you will have typechecking when calling the `makeMyObj` function and you will have dynamic `MyKeys` type generated

Comment: Oh, the `satisfies` operator is fantastic news.  Before this, I'd always have to do something like `as const`, but that prevents type safety *and* mutation.  Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 1):

I did figure out a way to use a wrapper function, but like I said in the OP, I'd rather not use this method.

```ts
interface MyInterface {
  someProp: number;
}

function makeMyObj<T extends Record<string, MyInterface>>(obj: T): { [key in keyof T]: T[key] } {
  return obj;
}

const MyObj = makeMyObj({
  myKey1: { someProp: 1 },
  myKey2: { someProp: 2 },
});

type MyKeys = keyof tyepof MyObj;
```

This method also doesn't get us complete type safety as it won't prevent addition properties from being added in the objects.

I also ran into an issue because I want `MyInterface` to include a member of type `MyKeys`, which creates a recursive definition.

Comment: May not be sexy, but it works!